# Подскажите как уменьшить блок кода if else в jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет недавно в интернете нашел такой блок кода (маленький)потом увеличил его.Ну теперь смотрю что я не могу добавить в него что та еще таким образом (я не профи в Jquery)выглядит отвратительно и не профессионально.Подскажите как можно уменьшить этот код правильно.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('.menu ').addClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').addClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').addClass("smaller");
    $('.next').addClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').addClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_right').addClass("normalize");
  } 
  else {
    $('.menu').removeClass("sticky");
    $('.blog').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.fullName').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_li').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.next').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.surname').removeClass("smaller");
    $('.menu_right').removeClass("normalize");
  }
});
```

Comment: Пока максимум что можно сделать, так это все селекторы, к которым применяется  `smaller`  написать так: `$('.blog, .fullName, .next, .surname').addClass("smaller");` ....... тоже самое с  `removeClass` ... другое скорее зависит от разметки и от того, какое назначение всех классов

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я немного доработал решение, которое предложил Oleg Reym. При таком подходе if вообще не нужен. Методу toggleClass вторым значением можно передать true или false, чтобы включить или выключить класс.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var isScrolled = $(this).scrollTop() > 1;
  $('body').toggleClass('scrolled', isScrolled);
});
```

Comment: Согласен, toggleClass хорош и, если честно, не доводилось юзать второй параметр, так что и я что-то узнал)))) Успехов!

Answer (score 3):

Измени немного разметку css. Т.е. при скролле пишешь

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
    $('body').addClass('scrolled'); // Лучше обернуть все дочерние классы в какой-нибудь #container
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

А в css пишешь:
Например, у тебя класс "sticky" имеет position:fixed; - в этом случае пишем:

```
body.scrolled .sticky { /* Либо же если выше в jQuery у тебя $('#container').addClass('scrolled'); - то в css  #container.scrolled .sticky {...} */
  position: fixed;
}
```

Т.е. у тебя есть общий "родитель" для всех элементов, которые должны меняться при скролле, и ты пишешь это все дело просто в css.

Если скинешь все стили - напишу код и объясню что к чему и почему.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('.menu ').addClass("sticky");
        $('.menu_right').addClass("normalize");
        $('.blog, fullName, next, surname').addClass("smaller");
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass("sticky");
        $('.menu_right').removeClass("normalize");
        $('.blog, fullName, menu_li, next, surname').removeClass("smaller");
    }
});
```

Comment: Селекторы можно дополнительно положить в переменную.